# Why $.getJSON is not working in this case

Tags: jquery

I have written a ajax request using getJSON of jQuery like below

```
 $.getJSON('bDays.json', function (bDy) { // This file exists in same folder path
      alert(1); // It is not executed..                     
 });
```

Even if I change the code to get .txt file.. It is not working.. Kindly let me know what could be the issue with my code

Comment: Please update the question to include the full URLs of the file containing the Javascript and the JSON file (they do not need to be publicly accessible, we just care about the paths). Also, can you confirm that `bDays.json` contains valid JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple things to try:

1. As pointed out by others, `bDays.json` must be accessible via an HTTP request. Try replacing `'bDays.json'` in your `getJSON` call with its full URL.
2. Make sure `bDays.json` contains valid JSON (run it through a validator, such as [this one](http://jsonlint.com/), to be certain if it is not obvious). The file needs to be valid JSON, as stated in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

   > As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently.

Answer (score 2):

[getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) uses a get HTTP request to retrieve json encoded data, it won't open a text file from your local drive.

The JSON data should be hosted on a webserver, and you can then reference its full URL.

Comment: I have tried to retrieve .txt file using $.get method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check that you write the code within `document.ready()` handler .

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('bDays.json', function (bDy) { 
      alert(1);          
 });
});
```

One thing, `$.getJSON()` can't parse or open a text file.

Comment: I have tried to retrieve .txt file using $.get method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Callback function is a *third* parameter:

```
 $.getJSON('bDays.json', null, function (bDy) { 
      alert(1);                    
 });
```

Also, try using a **full url** instead of just filename.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be so. Check the example at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Function definition is `jQuery.getJSON( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] )`. Maybe jQuery is checking the type of second parameter passed and if it's a function treats it as callback argument.